# Building libjepeg-turbo from source doesn't build the library libturbojpeg.so*

Tags: c, cmake, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I'm trying to build libjpeg-turbo from source to include 12 bit support. I downloaded the source code from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/) (2.0.1) then followed instruction given in Building.md

```
    cd libjpeg-turbo-2.0.1 
    mkdir build && cd build
    cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -D WITH_12BIT=1 -D WITH_TURBOJPEG=1 ..
    make -j8
    sudo make install
```

The compilation is successful and generates only `libjpeg.so`, `libjpeg.so.62` and `libjpeg.so.62.3.0` along with bunch of other binary files. But its not building the lib files `libturbojpeg.so.0.2.0`, `libturbojpeg.a` and `libturbojpeg.so` which i need. I'm not sure where I am going wrong. i have also tried without the `-D WITH_TURBOJPEG` flag.

I'm trying this on Ubuntu 16.04 on Nvidia Tx2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Line 201 of `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) turns `WITH_TURBOJPEG` off when building with `WITH_12BIT` enabled.

Don't enable `WITH_12BIT` and then `WITH_TURBOJPEG` will be default enabled and should build those libraries.

Comment: Added link to source on github.